# How to specify library version when using import in js?

Tags: javascript, multer, cloudinary

I am trying to import cloudinary to my project, and in their documentation it says that I have to use require and specify the version to v2 like this `const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;`. However, I have specified that my type in package.json as 'module', so I cannot use require I only have to say import. so, my question is how do I specify the version to v2. currently, I can upload to the cloudinary server, but I cannot get back the link to it. here is my cod:

my configuration

```
import multer from "multer";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import { CloudinaryStorage } from "multer-storage-cloudinary";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
});
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    folder: "ecommerce",
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

my route

```
productsRoutes.post("/products", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```

currently, the console log prints nothing when I submit the image, but it does upload it to the server.

sorry if my question is badly formatted, and any help is greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try ‘import {v2 as cloudinary} from “cloudinary”’

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks this worked

Answer (score 1):

My team and I had the same problem this week... If you didn't get to solve it we have looked into different possibilities and we got this simple but fine solution -> (**cloudinary: cloudinary.v2**). So the code will stay like this in our case:

```js
import multer from "multer"
import cloudinary  from 'cloudinary';
import {CloudinaryStorage} from "multer-storage-cloudinary";

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary.v2,
  params: {
    folder: "avatars",
    allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif"],
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
export default upload;
```

So you have to signal that you are using the v2 version on cloudinary in the CloudinaryStorage.
I hope that this helps even if it's 11 months late x). We just dealed with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer I used import {v2 as cloudinary} from “cloudinary”, and it worked.